# How to save data from a file which doesn't have column names?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have table with following fields:

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: scheme_details
#
#  id               :integer          not null, primary key
#  scheme_id        :integer          not null
#  nav_date         :datetime
#  nav_price        :float
#  repurchase_price :float
#  sale_price       :float
#  closing_date     :datetime
#  net_change       :float
#  prev_nav         :float
#  prev_nav_date    :datetime
#  upd_flag         :string(1)
#  created_at       :datetime         not null
#  updated_at       :datetime         not null
#  change           :float
#
```

Now I am getting a data file with `ace` file extension from ftp server, which doesn't have column names.

Following is sample data of file.

```
<<row>>1|5/24/2016 12:00:00 AM|1000.49|1000.49|1000.49||0|0|1000.49|5/23/2016 12:00:00 AM|A<</row>>
<<row>>2|5/24/2016 12:00:00 AM|2350.0193|2350.0193|2350.0193||0.0210084954593086|0.493599999999788|2349.5257|5/23/2016 12:00:00 AM|A<</row>>
<<row>>3|5/24/2016 12:00:00 AM|1005.4653|1005.4653|1005.4653||0.0210096133902824|0.211199999999963|1005.2541|5/23/2016 12:00:00 AM|A<</row>>
<<row>>4|5/24/2016 12:00:00 AM|1001.2549|1001.2549|1001.2549||0.0210080549857693|0.210300000000075|1001.0446|5/23/2016 12:00:00 AM|A<</row>>
<<row>>9|5/24/2016 12:00:00 AM|1005.428|1005.428|1005.428||0.0208611403115122|0.209699999999998|1005.2183|5/23/2016 12:00:00 AM|A<</row>>
<<row>>10|5/24/2016 12:00:00 AM|2226.3533|2226.3533|2226.3533||0.0208725620468016|0.464600000000246|2225.8887|5/23/2016 12:00:00 AM|A<</row>>
<<row>>11|5/24/2016 12:00:00 AM|1001.2478|1001.2478|1001.2478||0.0208683199024505|0.208899999999971|1001.0389|5/23/2016 12:00:00 AM|A<</row>>
<<row>>14|5/24/2016 12:00:00 AM|14.369|14.369|14.369||-0.567434779600033|-0.0820000000000007|14.451|5/23/2016 12:00:00 AM|A<</row>>
<<row>>15|5/24/2016 12:00:00 AM|33.37|33.37|33.37||-0.566150178784281|-0.190000000000005|33.56|5/23/2016 12:00:00 AM|A<</row>>
<<row>>22|5/24/2016 12:00:00 AM|15.87|15.87|15.87||-0.501567398119123|-0.0800000000000001|15.95|5/23/2016 12:00:00 AM|A<</row>>
<<row>>23|5/24/2016 12:00:00 AM|64.37|64.37|64.37||-0.540791100123601|-0.349999999999994|64.72|5/23/2016 12:00:00 AM|A<</row>>
<<row>>115|5/24/2016 12:00:00 AM|10.1146|10.1146|10.1146||-0.00197730058924853|-0.00020000000000131|10.1148|5/23/2016 12:00:00 AM|A<</row>>
<<row>>116|5/24/2016 12:00:00 AM|25.8745|25.8745|25.8745||-0.00193236714975395|-0.000499999999998835|25.875|5/23/2016 12:00:00 AM|A<</row>>
<<row>>117|5/24/2016 12:00:00 AM|10.3195|10.3195|10.3195||-0.00193804083451587|-0.000199999999999534|10.3197|5/23/2016 12:00:00 AM|A<</row>>
<<row>>118|5/24/2016 12:00:00 AM|10.317|10.317|10.317||-0.0019385104485668|-0.000199999999999534|10.3172|5/23/2016 12:00:00 AM|A<</row>>
<<row>>119|5/24/2016 12:00:00 AM|10.0863|10.0863|10.0863||-0.00198284836166692|-0.000199999999999534|10.0865|5/23/2016 12:00:00 AM|A<</row>>
<<row>>160|5/24/2016 12:00:00 AM|10.0729|10.0729|10.0729||0.0148936592727928|0.00150000000000006|10.0714|5/23/2016 12:00:00 AM|A<</row>>
<<row>>165|5/24/2016 12:00:00 AM|17.3863|17.3863|17.3863||0.0155318806231003|0.00269999999999726|17.3836|5/23/2016 12:00:00 AM|A<</row>>
<<row>>166|5/24/2016 12:00:00 AM|10.0315|10.0315|10.0315||0|0|10.0315|5/23/2016 12:00:00 AM|A<</row>>
```

I am able to parse the file and remove the unwanted data like `row` and split data using `|`.

Problem I am facing is how do I map the data to column names as the sample data file doesn't have column names and just data.

One solution I had was adding a dummy column names row on the top of the file through which I would be able to map the data.

But I am not sure if it is the right way to do so.

Any help or suggestion on how to solve this problem would be helpful.

Thank You!

Note: If you need to see the code which I have made I will be happy to provide.

Comment: Are you asking how to determine which column is which? I find it extremely unlikely anyone could do that - ask the creator of the data for some documentation

Comment: you can define a array and push all the splited values inside that, for each row.  Now map according to the index values of array with your schema.

Comment: thankx @PraveshKhatri I did exactly as you said and it worked thank you very much!

Comment: @FrederickCheung my issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you can define a array
2. push all the splited values inside that, for each row.
3. Now map according to the index values of array with your schema.

Answer (score 1):

You know their sequence from the table definition, so you would refer to the column by the index number. If a row is stored in variable `row`, the `id` field would be `row[0]`.

Of course this is not easy to read, and for better reading you could use constants:

```
ID = 0
.....
this_rows_id = row[ID]
```

If you don't like the manual definition of the mapping between column numbers and constant names, but have access to the schema definition, you could parse it and generate a tiny Ruby file which you then *`require`* into your program. This might be handy in the initial phase of a project, where schema definitions are likely to change.